# How do I use dateadd to get the first day of last year?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to pull data that falls in between January 1st, 2014 and today's date last year (ie. August 3rd, 2014). How would I go about using ``dateadd` to get the date 1/1/14? I'm using the following code to get the date 8/3/14.

`dateadd (yy, -1, getdate())`

I want to avoid explicitly searching for 1/1/14 because in a year's time I'd like the sql query to find 1/1/15 without me having to go back in and rewrite it.

Comment: [Some Common Date Routines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. For example, only more recent versions of SQL Server support [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate())-1, 0)
```

Comment: The DATEFROMPARTS() answer is probably better if you have Sql Server 2012 or later.

Comment: This worked for me as well and I like that I didn't have to convert anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: It might be worth noting this is only SQL 2012 and later

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL. Is there somewhere I can go to test that code out independent of my larger SQL query? And by that I mean somwhere where I just enter that code and shows me that it resolves to 1/1/14. Because right now I'm adding it to my SQL Query and I'm getting an error

Comment: `SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, 1, 1)` as a standalone query

Answer (score 0):

DATEFROMPARTS() is the best way but it requires SQL2012 or later. If you're on an earlier vierion, try this:

You can use `GETDATE()` to get the current date
You can use the function `YEAR()` to extract the year from any date
Subtract 1 from it to get last year
Append `1/1/` to the front of it
Convert it back to a date again

```
select convert(datetime, '1/1/' + convert(varchar(max),year(getdate())-1))
```

Comment: String functions/conversions are almost always the worst possible way to handle date problems.

Comment: @Joel I agree. Unless you're on an old version of SQL like 2008R2 in which case they may be the only thing in your tool chest. `DATEFROMPARTS()` is the better answer. This is offered as an alternative for earlier versions if you don't have SQL2012