# Concatenate string with numeric and convert into datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Working in SQL Server, I have a column that contains a year in numeric format. I need to make that year into a January 1st date of that 'year'. I've tried a few commands and the latest attempt is:

```
cast('01/01/' + X.[YEAR] as datetime)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797405/how-do-i-use-dateadd-to-get-the-first-day-of-last-year

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2010
SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year AS varchar) + '-1-1' AS DATETIME) -- 2010-01-01
```

Comment: That did the trick... I wasn't thinking I needed to convert the year into string... :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    select  GETDATE(),
            DATEADD (day, - DATEPART(dayofyear, GETDATE()) + 1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```